# Tailwind or regular css to fix img center and an anchor tag

Tags: html, css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I want the link not to work outside the img.

This is my code.
What do you think is the best way to center the img, I'm new web developer so need some professionals opinion =)

```css
.video__text-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="content max-w-4xl mx-auto">
  <div class="inner-content relative ">
    <a href="" class="z-10 left-0 top-0 w-full h-full absolute"></a>
    <img src="" alt="" class="">
    <div class="video__text-box flex justify-center absolute">
      <img class="h-12 lg:h-16 mr-4" src="" alt="">
      <div class="group flex flex-col text-left">
        <span class="text-dark-blue mb-1">xxxxxxx</span>
        <h2 class="text-4xl mb-0">watch video</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Because of the margin the link is clickable outside the img.

Comment: Should I just give max-height and max-width as the size of an image for the inner-content div? And margin auto?? Or is that the bad way?

Answer (score 0):

It's no point to mix tailwind with regular CSS just if you need to center the children inside the container. You can use `flex items-center justify-center`. But I suggest you to understand first CSS and after move to a CSS framework, if you understand CSS after you will write more naturally in any CSS framework.

Comment: Ah yes you are right. But I was asking about the link.. it's working outside the img due to the margin on the outer div. Is there an easy way to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

As @claudiu mentioned, there really is no point to mix tailwind with traditional CSS as tailwind is just a CSS framework like Bootstrap which is designed to avoid writing CSS.

With that being said, you can remove your `absolute`'s as absolute positioning will not pair well with `flex`. Then just adjust the order of your markup a bit and nest your `href` around the image you want to link to a video.

See it working here: [Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/cb82lqRFLT)

Another version with your traditional CSS. You should nest each `span` and `h2` in their own `a`. You are using `w-full` on those elements which is the same as `width: 100%;` allowing you to click them off the text. Use `w-fit` or `width: fit-content;` instead.

See that version here: [Tailwind Play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/2mrYtYhTra)

Comment: Oh that is really helpful. So avoid using traditional css and remove absolute, and nest span and h2 with anchor tag using w-fit. I will try thank you all!!

Comment: @Justina I mean you can use traditional CSS. But IMO it defeats the purpose of tailwind. Yes, the h2 and anchor had `w-full` meaning it will be the full length of the parent div. The image is in the parent div and it is stretching it. Therefore allows you to click in the spaces below the image where the text expands to. `w-fit` means the width is as much as the content inside of it.  In turn, this delimits the anchor and only makes only the text "clickable".